# Handle availability(disable) for multiple input fields in React

Tags: reactjs, forms, input-field

I want to manage the 'disable' attribute for multiple input fields. I have created a large form (over 30 inputs), and several of them will only be available if the previous checkbox is checked.

My current setup is something like the example below. In this example you can only select 'special_offers' if 'newsletter' is selected.

```
class Form extends React.Component {
  state={
     newsletter: false,
     specialOffers: false,
     disabled:true,
}

  handleChangeCheck = name => e => {
    this.setState({
      [name]: e.target.checked
    });
    if (name === 'newsletter') {
      this.checkNewsletterValue()
    }
  };
  checkNewsletterValue() {
    if(this.state.newsletter === true){ 
    this.setState( {disabled: !this.state.disabled} )
  } 
}
  render() {
    return(
        <div>

            <Checkbox name="newsletter" value={this.state.newsletter} 
            onChange={handleChangeCheck('newsletter')}>Sign up for news letter
            </Checkbox>

            <Checkbox name="special_offers" value={this.state.specialOffers} 
            onChange={handleChangeCheck('specialOffers')}  disabled = 
            {this.state.disabled}>
            Sign up special offers
            </Checkbox>

        </div>
    );
  }
};
```

My problem is that I would end up with an even larger state if I need to create a new state to change the 'disable' attribute for every single input field that is dependant on a previous selection.

Is there a way to create a generalised solution to handle all 'disable' values for my input fields?

Comment: you will have to create an array of object having parent child relationships

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that we have a key for each `input`, a key for each `checkbox`.

in this case we have `newsletter` and `special_offers`

the scenario I'm proposing is to have an array in state:
- `checkedBoxes` - to store the values of the names of the boxes that control whether the other boxes are allowed or not.

and in your default `handleChangeCheck`, each time a box that is checked, we push it's name to the array.

```
  handleChangeCheck = name => e => {
    let newCheckedBoxes = [...this.state.checkedBoxes]//don't forget to add a default value for that in the state as an array.
    //conditionally add or remove the items.
    if(newCheckedBoxes.indexOf(name)){
        newCheckedBoxes = newCheckedBoxes.filter(_name => _name !== name);
    } else {
        newCheckedBoxes.push(name);
    }
    e.target.checked && newCheckedBoxes.push(name)
    this.setState({
      [name]: e.target.checked,
      checkedBoxes: newCheckedBoxes,
    });
  };
```

and in your conditionally disabled boxes.

```
<Checkbox
  name="special_offers"
  value={this.state.specialOffers} 
  onChange={handleChangeCheck('specialOffers')}
  disabled={!this.state.checkedBoxes.includes('newsletter')}>
    Sign up special offers
</Checkbox>
```

Comment: Brilliant! This looks like a good solution to my problem. I will try to implement this to my project later today, will post update. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Lars and Good luck!

Comment: Cool, it worked! However I needed to add functionality for removing it again once unchecked, otherwise it only works the first time.

Comment: Oh, and would be cool if you could upvote the question to help me reach 15 reputation :)

Answer (score 0):

Well you could try using **hooks**, instead of the classic component. It would reduce the bloat, and also with some custom hook you could reduce the entire function to only one function where you only send the checked one and the checkboxes that the checked one affect

> **What is a Hook?** A Hook is a special function that lets you “hook into”
>   React features. For example, useState is a Hook that lets you add
>   React state to function components. We’ll learn other Hooks later.
>
> **When would I use a Hook?** If you write a function component and realize
>   you need to add some state to it, previously you had to convert it to
>   a class. Now you can use a Hook inside the existing function
>   component. We’re going to do that right now!

[What's a Hook?](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#whats-a-hook)

By the way, don't "try" hooks, if you still can in your APP, move them to hooks, they are cleaner and faster.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I will consider using hooks.